# Large file to merge. How to do prevent duplicates in merge in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by, out-of-memory

I have two dataframes which when merged create a 50 GB file which is too much for python to handle. I couldn't even merge in python and had to do it in SQLite.

This is what the two data set look like

first dataset:

```
        a_id c_consumed
    0    sam        oil
    1    sam      bread
    2    sam       soap
    3  harry      shoes
    4  harry        oil
    5  alice       eggs
    6  alice        pen
    7  alice    eggroll
```

Code for producing this dataset

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a_id': 'sam sam sam harry harry alice alice alice'.split(),
               'c_consumed': 'oil bread soap shoes oil eggs pen eggroll'.split()})
```

Second dataset:

```
       a_id b_received brand_id type_received       date
   0    sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01
   1    sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02
   2    sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01
   3  harry        oil    chris      clothing 2011-01-02
   4  harry      shoes    nancy       edibles 2011-01-03
   5  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03
   6  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02
   7  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03
```

code for producing this dataset:

```
  df_id = pd.DataFrame({'a_id': 'sam sam sam harry harry alice alice alice'.split(),
                  'b_received': 'soap oil brush oil shoes beer brush eggs'.split(),
                  'brand_id': 'bill chris dan chris nancy peter dan jaju'.split(),
                  'type_received': 'edibles utility grocery clothing edibles breakfast cleaning edibles'.split()})
 date3 = ['2011-01-01','2011-01-02','2011-01-01','2011-01-02','2011-01-03','2011-01-03','2011-01-02','2011-01-03']
 date3 = pd.to_datetime(date3)
 df_id['date']= date3
```

I use this code for merging the dataset

```
 combined = pd.merge(df_id,df,on='a_id',how='left')
```

And this is the resulting dataset

```
      a_id b_received brand_id type_received       date c_consumed
 0     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01        oil
 1     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01      bread
 2     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01       soap
 3     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02        oil
 4     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02      bread
 5     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02       soap
 6     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01        oil
 7     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01      bread
 8     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01       soap
 9   harry        oil    chris      clothing 2011-01-02      shoes
10  harry        oil    chris      clothing 2011-01-02        oil
11  harry      shoes    nancy       edibles 2011-01-03      shoes
12  harry      shoes    nancy       edibles 2011-01-03        oil
13  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03       eggs
14  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03        pen
15  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03    eggroll
16  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02       eggs
17  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02        pen
18  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02    eggroll
19  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03       eggs
20  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03        pen
21  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03    eggroll
```

What I want to know is if a person consumed the product received, and I need to keep the rest of the information since I will later need to see if it was affected by the brand or product type. In order to do this I use the following code to create a new column which gives me the following result.

Code:

```
  combined['output']= (combined.groupby('a_id')
           .apply(lambda x : x['b_received'].isin(x['c_consumed']).astype('i4'))
           .reset_index(level='a_id', drop=True))
```

The resulting data frame is

```
       a_id b_received brand_id type_received       date c_consumed  output
  0     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01        oil       1
  1     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01      bread       1
  2     sam       soap     bill       edibles 2011-01-01       soap       1
  3     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02        oil       1
  4     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02      bread       1
  5     sam        oil    chris       utility 2011-01-02       soap       1
  6     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01        oil       0
  7     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01      bread       0
  8     sam      brush      dan       grocery 2011-01-01       soap       0
  9   harry        oil    chris      clothing 2011-01-02      shoes       1
 10  harry        oil    chris      clothing 2011-01-02        oil       1
 11  harry      shoes    nancy       edibles 2011-01-03      shoes       1
 12  harry      shoes    nancy       edibles 2011-01-03        oil       1
 13  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03       eggs       0
 14  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03        pen       0
 15  alice       beer    peter     breakfast 2011-01-03    eggroll       0
 16  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02       eggs       0
 17  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02        pen       0
 18  alice      brush      dan      cleaning 2011-01-02    eggroll       0
 19  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03       eggs       1
 20  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03        pen       1
 21  alice       eggs     jaju       edibles 2011-01-03    eggroll       1
```

As you can see the results of output are wrong, what I really want is a dataset which is more like this

```
      a_id b_received brand_id c_consumed type_received       date  output 
 0    sam       soap     bill        oil       edibles 2011-01-01       1   
 1    sam        oil    chris        NaN       utility 2011-01-02       1   
 2    sam      brush      dan       soap       grocery 2011-01-03       0   
 3  harry        oil    chris      shoes      clothing 2011-01-04       1   
 4  harry      shoes    nancy        oil       edibles 2011-01-05       1   
 5  alice       beer    peter       eggs     breakfast 2011-01-06       0   
 6  alice      brush      dan      brush      cleaning 2011-01-07       1   
 7  alice       eggs     jaju        NaN       edibles 2011-01-08       1
```

I can take care of duplication after merging, using drop_duplicates, but the resulting dataframe is too big to merge.

I really need the duplication to be taken care of during the merging or before it, because the resulting dataframe is too big for python to handle and it gives me memory error.

Any suggestions on how to improve my merge or any other way to get the output column without merging?

At the end, all I need is the date column and the output column to calculate log odds, and create a timeseries. But I am stuck at merging the files because of the size.

Comment: why don't you want to do it in SQLite? IMO, SQLite (or any other RDBMS) would be much more efficient for that

Comment: Does the column `a_id` always match on both dataframes?  It looks like you want to do a horizontal concatenation instead of a merge.

Comment: @MaxU I don't know much about SQLite, also even in SQLite when I merged them it took me more than 7 hours to merge the two files and my computer froze for that time

Comment: @AmitSinghParihar, i would recommend you to use a bit more powerful RDBMS for such amount of data, for example MySQL (it's free). And in any RDBMS, you are using, first create indexes on both tables on the joining column (a_id). Are you sure you need left outer join (merge in terms of Pandas), would it work with an "inner join"?

Comment: @MaxU, when I try innerjoin, it takes away the rows with null values, I need the null values later to calculate the length of the column to calculate proabability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I performed two groupby operations to get the output table.  I added `b_received` to the keys on which to group, and I took the first value on the second groupby given that all values are identical for this grouping level.

```
output = ((combined
           .groupby(['a_id', 'b_received'])
           .apply(lambda x : x['b_received'].isin(x['c_consumed'])
           .astype(int)))
          .groupby(level=[0, 1])
          .first())

output.name = 'output'

>>> (df_id[['a_id', 'b_received', 'date']]
     .merge(output.reset_index(), on=['a_id', 'b_received']))
    a_id b_received       date  output
0    sam       soap 2011-01-01       1
1    sam        oil 2011-01-02       1
2    sam      brush 2011-01-01       0
3  harry        oil 2011-01-02       1
4  harry      shoes 2011-01-03       1
5  alice       beer 2011-01-03       0
6  alice      brush 2011-01-02       0
7  alice       eggs 2011-01-03       1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works with the merged datafile. However, my problem is also the size of file that is made when merging, its not supported and python gives memory error. The output function that you created is based on the condition that there's a merged file ('combined'). I realized when I tried to apply the merge function for combining the dataframes it doesn't happen. Anyways I can get the final df without doing merge?

Comment: my constraint is in creating the 'combined' dataframe. for the purpose of illustration here I made it, but my actual code can't merge the two dataframes (df,df_id). Merging them gives me memory error.                                 Now your code is perfect, but when you create the output, it uses the 'combine' data frame, but I can't make the combine dataframe because of the sheer size of it. Therefore, I can't use the output code, without which the second code also doesn't work.

Comment: I tried splitting the data in 1/5th, the merge worked, but it then  gave me a memory error again while running the above two pieces of code.

Comment: the final file comes out to be 50 GB after merging (that was after I merged using SQLite, but then couldn't even get it in pandas). I have 16GB RAM and a quad core.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104134/discussion-between-amit-singh-parihar-and-alexander).

Comment: I was able to do it by splitting the file in 10 chunks and applying your function. Then I just wrote them in a csv, opened a new file, read all the csv and then concatenated them. Thank you for your input

Comment: Glad it finally worked! BTW, python can handle, it is hardware constraints that cause the problem.  Also, could I trouble you for an upvote and acceptance tick if this solved your issue? Thx.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I have started looking into pytables. Apparently it can handle large datasets well